# djcelery periodic poll data store in redis db?

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

I am having Django-celery implemented a Django project, and getting poll data from external API inside celery periodic task. I wanted to keep this data for other tasks of celery. using Redis how can achieve?? please give me brief explanation?? I am new to celery and Redis thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the schedule in database you can use django-celery-beat database backed periodic task.
https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/